# Doctrine: Symfony2 Listener vs inclass Lifecycle callbacks

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been working with an image entity that when persisted, uses internal methods to save/move/delete the image file associated using hook annotations but I feel somewhat like the entity itself should be only relevant getters and setters.

**Should I leave the methods in the entity or move them to a listener class?**

The entity has methods that:

- generate unique filename/path
- save the image file to disk on persist
- remove the image on cascade remove.

But I'm unsure I like this being in my entity..

```
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if(null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // throws exception on error - stopping persist
    $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->url);

    if(isset($this->tmp)) {
        unlink($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/'. $this->tmp);
        $this->tmp = null;
    }

    $this->file = null;
}
```

So I was thinking of moving them into a listener class, using methods like the sample below, however I don't like the idea of it checking every type of entity persist and only caring about the 'image' entities:

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof Image) {
        // ... do something with the Product
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($entity instanceof Image) {
    $entity->upload();
}` sounds like the correct way to do it

Comment: That seems counter productive, as id need a listener AND the methods on the model.   I'm asking which is the correct way, a listener OR entity methods with hook annotations

Comment: Both ways are correct, choose the one that fits your project better. I quote from the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events): *"Lifecycle event listeners are much more powerful than the simple lifecycle callbacks that are defined on the entity classes. They sit at a level above the entities and **allow you to implement re-usable behaviors across different entity classes**."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the use case. Quoting from the [cookbook on how to handle file uploads](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-lifecycle-callbacks):

> Using lifecycle callbacks is a limited technique that has some drawbacks. If you want to remove the hardcoded **DIR** reference inside the Document::getUploadRootDir() method, the best way is to start using explicit doctrine listeners. There you will be able to inject kernel parameters such as kernel.root_dir to be able to build absolute paths.

If you want the best of both worlds you could use **Entity Listeners**. This listener will only be fired on that single entity instead of listening to all of them:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html
- http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/02/18/symfony2-doctrine-2-entity-listeners/

I also recommend looking at the [Uploadable Doctrine Extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md) which should offer all the functionality you need.

It also offers setting a default upload path:
http://www.obverse.com/2013/03/the-trick-to-getting-gedmo-uploadable-working-with-sonata-admin/

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    uploadable:
        # Default file path: This is one of the three ways you can configure the path for the Uploadable extension
        default_file_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads
```